# Using cout to print a statement only once in a function that is repeatedly called

Tags: c++, console, cout

Is it possible to print a line of text using `cout` in windows, to the console only once inside a function that is repeatedly called or updated?

To give some scope, I have a keyboard input function that is called to check for key presses and when I press `"C"` my camera's values are updated and I print out confirmation to the console like this: `cout << "\nView switched to 'Default View`..." << endl;` but it prints it forever in a infinite loop.

This may sound like a simple question, but this is the first time I've come across and issue like this.

```
void keyboard()
{
   if (CAM_DEF) //switch to default view
   {
       cout << "\nView switched to 'Default View`..." << endl;
       Q_PRESSED = false;
       E_PRESSED = false;
   }
    ... //more key presses
}
```

Comment: Show much more of your source code. We cannot precisely understand or guess what exactly you are talking about.

Comment: I've described exactly what I'm talking about. It's to do with the behaviour, regardless of what code it is implemented within.

Comment: move the view switching up to the calling code, or higher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a static local variable to guard against the print happening multiple times:

```
void function()
{
    static bool runOnce= true;

    if(runOnce)
    {
        cout << //print stuff
        runOnce = false;
    }
    ... do other stuff
}
```

OR a C++11 fancy pants answer using a lambda, which is shorter but arguably less readable:

```
using namespace std;

void function()
{
    static const auto runOnce = [] { cout << "Hello" << endl; return true;}();
}

int main()
{
    function();
    function();
    function();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Hello
```

Comment: A bit of a hack to make this shorter would be something like `static auto unused = std::cout << stuff;`

Comment: @chris: In this case, you need to make that a reference, since `ostream` is not copyable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Oops, right.